# how to set variable value in mysql CREATE TABLE query? Java

Tags: java, mysql

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE user_post_data ("+str+" varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob, post_date date, like varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date )";
```

Here, `str` is the String representing email of a user. I want to create one column of email id of the user but i am getting this error below:

> Unclosed string literal: pointing at ..."+str+" ...

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: `like` is a `KEYWORD` in `SQL`, try avoiding usage of `keywords` and make sure `str` is not empty.

Comment: You do realize that you are only going to have one table in this database called user_post_data?  And that the table will have a column corresponding to only one email address? I don't really see the purpose of making a column name an email of the user.  Is each user going to have a separate database?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `column`name with special characters like `@` and `.` in it.

I believe Email ID has an `@` in it, so it will not create a table.

Also make sure `keywords` are not used as column names. `like` is a keyword.

try creating a table by replacing `@` and `.` with some other characters like `$`

```
String str = "example$gmail_com"

String query = "create table newTable("+str+" varchar(255));";
```

Comment: Your string `str` is a `null` string, do give a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Like is a reserved word in SQL and can not be used as column name directly
in order to achieve like as a column name you need to put it as **`like`**

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE user_post_data ("+str+" varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob, post_date date, `like` varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date )";
```

so hopefully this will run fine

[for more details check out this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is enclose your variable like this within the sql statement

'"+variable+"'

so your statement will read :

```
"CREATE TABLE user_post_data ('"+str+"' varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob, post_date date, like varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date )";
```