# setting variable value in mysql CREATE TABLE query ? Java

Tags: java, mysql

thank you for your comments for my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747532/how-to-set-variable-value-in-mysql-create-table-query-java/30747835#30747835)

I have tried making changes to my query accordingly with a change in table name:

```
String str = getEmail();

String query = " CREATE TABLE "+str+"(email varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob,  post_time timestamp, post_date date, likes varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date) ";

pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);

int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Now here is an error in syntax:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: near.." '**null**(email varchar(255).."
```

I don't know why **null**?? And what is the error here?

I am very new to Mysql..so please excuse n help..
much appreciated..thnx

Comment: `getEmail()` returns null.

Comment: what does getEmail(); return.. implementation please..

Comment: Please post your `getEmail()` code here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `getEmail();` returns `null`. So your table name is null and you get these error message.
Check it before calling the create statement.

You should not use special character in a table name. If you want to do this, you have to escape the tablename with backticks:

```
String query = " CREATE TABLE `"+str+"` (email varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob,  post_time timestamp, post_date date, likes varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date) ";
```

Comment: should be a comment :)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Do not think so. Because that is the solution of OP's problem.

Comment: I passed 'str' value as:

String str = "info$gmail.com";
String query = " CREATE TABLE "+str+" (email varchar(255), post_text varchar(255), post_image longblob,  post_time timestamp, post_date date, likes varchar(255), like_time timestamp, like_date date) ";

Now the error shows:..Unknown Database 'info$gmail.com' ..' 
In Mysql I have  Database named "Community" and have obtained a connection already..now i want a table named "info$gmail.com" to be created in that DB. 

In the sql query isn't "+str+" supposed to be a table name instead of database name?..

Comment: @HarshVardhan Do not use an Email address with special characters as table name. If you want to do it you have to escapte it by using backticks arround: String query = " CREATE TABLE `"+str+"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` String is `null`. Please give a value to it.

```
String str = getEmail();
if(str != null)
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```